# When open Keyboard shows overflow in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, overflow

In my case, I have a rounded background for all inputs (attached image1) but when I click to the last TextField I get an overflow warning (attached image2) and can't scroll down.

I have tried using in Scaffold `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` but the last TextField goes under the keyboard, so it is not what I want.

[my code at gist](https://gist.github.com/Abdugani-Temirbaev/5b1f8e69f46cbb6c63e943bad68b3c3c)

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` widget with the `Expanded` widget. This is the only thing that you need.

```
          Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded( // Wrap with Expanded!
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(32.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(32.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                                child: Text('Sign Up',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it good solution, but I need rounded box with content placed at bottom, if wrap with `Expanded` that box moves to top

Comment: Ok, then you can add a Spacer() widget before Expanded widget like this:   `Spacer(),
                Expanded(//...`

Comment: Or you can add another Expanded widget with flex values like:   `Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                  flex: 2,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 9,`

Comment: Great thank you, I use your fist suggestion but instead Expanded use `Flexible` with              `flex: 1, fit: FlexFit.loose,`

Answer (score 2):

wrap you code with `SingleChildScrollView`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
child:Stack(
...))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to all text field wrap in `Listview` widget.

Comment: Thank you, but no it is not helped

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Abdugani-Temirbaev/5b1f8e69f46cbb6c63e943bad68b3c3c